# How to set the window size and position programmatically for a SpriteKit/GameScene app on OSX

Tags: swift, macos, sprite-kit

I have a bare-bones project created in Xcode as a SpriteKit/GameScene app. I want to set the window size programmatically. I've read a lot of answers here, and several tutorials elsewhere, but none of the things I've read have helped.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32882548/how-to-set-the-position-and-size-programatically-for-the-main-window) talks about overriding `WindowController.windowDidLoad`, but GameScene doesn't give me a `WindowController`. It does give me a `ViewController`. [This tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/71-spritekit-tutorial-for-beginners) says you can call `self.view.window?.setFrame()` from `ViewController.viewDidLoad()`, but my window stubbornly remains the same size. A number of the answers I've found on SO talk about auto-layout. I don't have anything to lay out. It's just a SpriteKit starter project.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48516221/nswindow-launching-with-wrong-size-after-setting-contentviewcontroller-to-nstabv) says you can set `preferredContentSize` in `ViewController.viewWillAppear()`, and that does in fact let me set the window size, but if I make the window too big (because I had to guess at a legitimate size), it's not draggable or resizable. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32677444/unable-to-set-the-right-size-for-the-gamescene-in-spritekit-swift) says you can get the correct size from `view.bounds.size`, but that says 800 x 600, which is nowhere near the size of my screen. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34349682/spritekit-how-to-get-correct-screen-size) says you can get the bounds from `UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size`, but my GameScene/SpriteKit starter project seems not to have any kind of `UIScreen` in it.

How can I get the screen size, and how can I set the window size and position programmatically?

Also, one of the other answers, which I can't seem to find any more, says you should delete `GameScene.sks`, which I did, and everything seems fine still, except for the size.

Comment: "GameScene doesn't give me a WindowController"  Que!?  The base view controller should be connected its window controller.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know what those words mean, or how I could make use of them. Cheers

Comment: If your project didn't give you a window controller, you can add one through Interface Builder for yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be awesome if some UI guru could comment on whether this is the "right" answer, but here's what I did as a wild guess based on "El Tomato's" rather cryptic comments. First, add the following to ViewController.swift:

```
class WildGuessWindowController: NSWindowController {
    override func windowDidLoad() {
        if let screenSize = window?.screen?.frame {
            window!.setFrame(screenSize, display: true)
            print(screenSize)
        }

        super.windowDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Next, open Main.storyboard in the project navigator. You might see something like the following: 
[image]

Click on the box that says "Window Controller", and open the right-hand side panel. You should see something like this.

[image]

Notice the box next to the arrow, that has a grayed-out class name in it. (Also notice that you might have to click the "Identity inspector" button, the blue one above where it says "Custom Class".) Now click that drop-down, and you should see `WildGuessWindowController`. Select that, and you're set. Build and run. The framework will instantiate your class, and run `windowDidLoad()`.

Answer (score 3):

## Updated for Swift 5

### Window Size

Remember to add `NSWindowDelegate` to your `NSViewController` class if you wish to implement it there (ie. `viewDidLoad()`, `viewWillAppear()`, `viewDidAppear()`, etc.)

#### NSView

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, NSWindowDelegate {

    override func viewWillAppear() {
        fillWindow()
    }
    
    /// Sizes window to fill max screen size
    func fillWindow() {
        if let screenSize = view.window?.screen?.frame {
            view.window!.setFrame(screenSize, display: true)
        }
    }

}
```

#### NSWindow

```
class WindowController: NSWindowController {

    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()
    
        fillWindow()
    }

    /// Sizes window to fill max screen size
    func fillWindow() {
        if let screenSize = window?.screen?.frame {
            window!.setFrame(screenSize, display: true)
        }
    }

}
```

**Print to Debugger Console**

```
print(screenSize)    // embed within if let screenSize { ... }
```

---

### Window Position

See the full answer, with implemented code, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66140320/1234120).

```
extension NSWindow {
    
    /// Positions the `NSWindow` at the horizontal-vertical center of the `visibleFrame` (takes Status Bar and Dock sizes into account)
    public func positionCenter() {
        if let screenSize = screen?.visibleFrame.size {
            self.setFrameOrigin(NSPoint(x: (screenSize.width-frame.size.width)/2, y: (screenSize.height-frame.size.height)/2))
        }
    }
    /// Centers the window within the `visibleFrame`, and sizes it with the width-by-height dimensions provided.
    public func setCenterFrame(width: Int, height: Int) {
        if let screenSize = screen?.visibleFrame.size {
            let x = (screenSize.width-frame.size.width)/2
            let y = (screenSize.height-frame.size.height)/2
            self.setFrame(NSRect(x: x, y: y, width: CGFloat(width), height: CGFloat(height)), display: true)
        }
    }
    /// Returns the center x-point of the `screen.visibleFrame` (the frame between the Status Bar and Dock).
    /// Falls back on `screen.frame` when `.visibleFrame` is unavailable (includes Status Bar and Dock).
    public func xCenter() -> CGFloat {
        if let screenSize = screen?.visibleFrame.size { return (screenSize.width-frame.size.width)/2 }
        if let screenSize = screen?.frame.size { return (screenSize.width-frame.size.width)/2 }
        return CGFloat(0)
    }
    /// Returns the center y-point of the `screen.visibleFrame` (the frame between the Status Bar and Dock).
    /// Falls back on `screen.frame` when `.visibleFrame` is unavailable (includes Status Bar and Dock).
    public func yCenter() -> CGFloat {
        if let screenSize = screen?.visibleFrame.size { return (screenSize.height-frame.size.height)/2 }
        if let screenSize = screen?.frame.size { return (screenSize.height-frame.size.height)/2 }
        return CGFloat(0)
    }

}
```

---

### Usage

#### NSWindow

Positions the existing window to the center of visibleFrame.

```
window!.positionCenter()
```

Sets a new window frame, at the center of visibleFrame, with dimensions

```
window!.setCenterFrame(width: 900, height: 600)
```

#### NSView

Using `xCenter()` and `yCenter()` to get the central x-y points of the `visibleFrame`.

```
let x = self.view.window?.xCenter() ?? CGFloat(0)
let y = self.view.window?.yCenter() ?? CGFloat(0)
self.view.window?.setFrame(NSRect(x: x, y: y, width: CGFloat(900), height: CGFloat(600)), display: true)
```